# ignore repeated keystrokes for more than 2 seconds in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, accessibility

Windows 7 Pro ease of access center allows you to ignore repeated keystrokes for a maximum of 2.0 seconds. For my purposes, I need repeated keystrokes ignored for upwards of 240 seconds. Is there somewhere I can override this 2 second maximum?

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to export your registry using regedit before and after you make a change to this value and then use winmerge on the exports to see what changed and try increasing it to a larger value than 2 and then rebooting.

If that doesn't work, I bet you could solve this using autohotkey - if you can't find out how, try asking in their forums.

Comment: I was just exploring autohotkey, having a bit of trouble with the scripting but there may be a solution there. Thanks for the recommendation.

I was thinking it would be somewhere in regedit but I'm not sure where to start looking for where that value may exist in the registry. If you have an idea of where to look that would be amazing, I'd look at that solution as well. Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, it was outrageously easy to find.

HKEY_USERS -> .DEFAULT -> Control Panel -> Accessibility -> Keyboard Response if anyone wants to know.

Comment: regedit worked like a charm. I changed the values for BounceTime and Last BounceKey Setting to 10000 for both current user and all users and something in there worked. The bouncekey is activated for 10 seconds now and is disabled when I turn filter keys off. Thank you!